# libs not found in Visual Studio Code after installation

Tags: python, matplotlib, visual-studio-code

I installed Visual Code fresh
and installed Python 3.
In VSC I added matplotlib using `pip install matplotlib`

Which now gives me this result

```
PS Z:\phyton> pip install matplotlib
Requirement already satisfied: matplotlib in c:\users\matth\appdata\local\packages\pythonsoftwarefoundation.python.3.9_qbz5n2kfra8p0\localcache\local-packages\python39\site-packages (3.5.1)
Requirement already satisfied: cycler>=0.10 in c:\users\matth\appdata\local\packages\pythonsoftwarefoundation.python.3.9_qbz5n2kfra8p0\localcache\local-packages\python39\site-packages (from matplotlib) (0.11.0)
Requirement already satisfied: python-dateutil>=2.7 in c:\users\matth\appdata\local\packages\pythonsoftwarefoundation.python.3.9_qbz5n2kfra8p0\localcache\local-packages\python39\site-packages (from matplotlib) (2.8.2)  
Requirement already satisfied: packaging>=20.0 in c:\users\matth\appdata\local\packages\pythonsoftwarefoundation.python.3.9_qbz5n2kfra8p0\localcache\local-packages\python39\site-packages (from matplotlib) (21.3)        
Requirement already satisfied: kiwisolver>=1.0.1 in c:\users\matth\appdata\local\packages\pythonsoftwarefoundation.python.3.9_qbz5n2kfra8p0\localcache\local-packages\python39\site-packages (from matplotlib) (1.3.2)     
Requirement already satisfied: numpy>=1.17 in c:\users\matth\appdata\local\packages\pythonsoftwarefoundation.python.3.9_qbz5n2kfra8p0\localcache\local-packages\python39\site-packages (from matplotlib) (1.22.1)
Requirement already satisfied: pyparsing>=2.2.1 in c:\users\matth\appdata\local\packages\pythonsoftwarefoundation.python.3.9_qbz5n2kfra8p0\localcache\local-packages\python39\site-packages (from matplotlib) (3.0.6)      
Requirement already satisfied: fonttools>=4.22.0 in c:\users\matth\appdata\local\packages\pythonsoftwarefoundation.python.3.9_qbz5n2kfra8p0\localcache\local-packages\python39\site-packages (from matplotlib) (4.28.5)    
Requirement already satisfied: pillow>=6.2.0 in c:\users\matth\appdata\local\packages\pythonsoftwarefoundation.python.3.9_qbz5n2kfra8p0\localcache\local-packages\python39\site-packages (from matplotlib) (9.0.0)
Requirement already satisfied: six>=1.5 in c:\users\matth\appdata\local\packages\pythonsoftwarefoundation.python.3.9_qbz5n2kfra8p0\localcache\local-packages\python39\site-packages (from python-dateutil>=2.7->matplotlib)
```

But In the editor the import is still marked as not installed and also does not execute in the debugger:

```
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import numpy as np
```

Why does it fail. And why is everthing installed in such a wired path?

Answer (score 0):

When we install modules, they are located in `installation\python\lib\site-packages`.

[image]

Run `python --version` in integrated Terminal, Python should be as the same as the one shown in status bar. Reload window, see if you can import modules successfully.

If not, turn to folder explorer, delete installed modules.

To avoid messing up global python environment, it's recommended that you create a virtual environment:

1. Open an new integrated Terminal, run `python -m venv .venv`
2. Open Command Palette, select `.venv\Scripts\python.exe` as interpreter
3. Open an new integrated Terminal again, which will activate the environment in terminal, then go on module installation.

For your reference: [Create a virtual environment](https://code.visualstudio.com/docs/python/environments#_create-a-virtual-environment) && [Select and activate an environment](https://code.visualstudio.com/docs/python/environments#_select-and-activate-an-environment)